# How to define a function with two enum parameters where the 2nd type is determined by the 1st?

Tags: rust

I'm working on the [rust-efl](https://github.com/arlowhite/rust-efl) project, which is a binding to the [Enlightenment EFL](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-efl) C library.

There is a function that takes two C-style enums to configure the library. I want to restrict the second argument to a certain enum based on the value of the first argument.

I'll use the actual code for this example since it makes it a bit easier to understand the use case.

Example call:

```
elementary::policy_set(ElmPolicy::Quit, ElmPolicyQuit::LastWindowClosed as i32);
```

Library Rust code:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub enum ElmPolicy {
    /// under which circumstances the application should quit automatically. See ElmPolicyQuit
    Quit = 0,
    /// defines elm_exit() behaviour. See ElmPolicyExit
    Exit,
    /// defines how throttling should work. See ElmPolicyThrottle
    Throttle
}
#[repr(C)]
pub enum ElmPolicyQuit {
    /// never quit the application automatically
    None = 0,
    /// quit when the application's last window is closed
    LastWindowClosed,
    /// quit when the application's last window is hidden
    LastWindowHidden
}

pub fn policy_set(policy: ElmPolicy, value: i32) {
```

There is an enum similar to `ElmPolicyQuit` for each value of `ElmPolicy`. The second argument to `policy_set` should be of the corresponding enum type.

I would like to modify `policy_set` so that the caller does not have to cast the value to an `i32` by defining a type for `value`. Ideally, I would like Rust to check that the second argument is of the correct type for the given `policy` argument.

**Implementation Attempt**

I'm new to Rust, so this may be way off, but this is my current attempt:

```
pub fn policy_set<P: ElmPolicy, V: ElmPolicyValue<P>>(policy: P, value: V) {
    unsafe { elm_policy_set(policy as c_int, value as c_int) }
}

trait ElmPolicyValue<P> {}
impl ElmPolicyValue<ElmPolicy::Quit> for ElmPolicyQuit {}
```

But I get this error:

> src/elementary.rs:246:22: 246:31 error: `ElmPolicy` is not a trait
>   [E0404] src/elementary.rs:246 pub fn policy_set>(policy: P, value: V) {

*(arrow points to first argument's type)*

I made a dummy trait for ElmPolicy, but then I get

> src/elementary.rs:111:21: 111:36 error: found value
>   `elementary::ElmPolicy::Quit` used as a type [E0248]
>   src/elementary.rs:111 impl ElmPolicyValue for
>   ElmPolicyQuit {}

So it seems like I can't use enums for generic types in this way.
What is the correct way to implement this?

I suppose I don't need these to actually be enums. I just need the values to be convertible to a `c_int` that corresponds with the EFL library's C enum.

Also, I thought about a single argument instead.

```
elementary::policy_set(elementary::Policy::Quit::LastWindowClosed);
```

But nested C-like enums don't seem to work despite documentation I found and I'm uncertain about using `#[repr(C)]` with nested enums.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it: instead of defining `ElmPolicy` as an `enum`, I'd define it as a trait with an associated type that specifies the parameter type for the policy's value. Each policy would define a unit struct that implements `ElmPolicy`.

```
pub trait ElmPolicy {
    type Value;
}

pub struct ElmPolicyQuit;

impl ElmPolicy for ElmPolicyQuit {
    type Value = ElmPolicyQuitValue;
}

// TODO: ElmPolicyExit and ElmPolicyThrottle

#[repr(C)]
pub enum ElmPolicyQuitValue {
    /// never quit the application automatically
    None = 0,
    /// quit when the application's last window is closed
    LastWindowClosed,
    /// quit when the application's last window is hidden
    LastWindowHidden
}

pub fn policy_set<P: ElmPolicy>(policy: P, value: P::Value) {
    // TODO
}

fn main() {
    policy_set(ElmPolicyQuit, ElmPolicyQuitValue::LastWindowClosed);
    //policy_set(ElmPolicyQuit, ElmPolicyQuitValue::LastWindowClosed as i32); // does not compile
}
```

You can add methods or supertraits to `ElmPolicy` and contraints to `ElmPolicy::Value` as necessary. For example, you might want to add `Into<i32>` as a constraint on `ElmPolicy::Value`, so that you can use `value.into()` in `policy_set` to convert the value to an `i32`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to solve both problems in one swoop. Create a straight-forward Rust binding to the C library that exposes the API as is (a [`*-sys` package](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages)). Then provide a more idiomatic Rust API on top:

```
enum ElmPolicy {
    Quit(QuitDetail),
    Exit(ExitDetail),
    Throttle(ThrottleDetail),
}

enum QuitDetail {
    None,
    LastWindowClosed,
    LastWindowHidden,
}
```

Then you can create methods on `ElmPolicy` that produce a tuple of the C enums, or directly calls the appropriate C function, as desired.

Note that there is likely to be a bit of boilerplate as your enums in the `*-sys` crate will mirror those in the idiomatic API and you will want to convert between them. Macros may help reduce that.

Comment: Ok, I've been thinking about how much to modify the API to be more Rust friendly. Do you have a good example of a project following this *-sys pattern or an article on it?

Comment: @Arlo i was a bit lazy before and have now linked to a resource. Is that useful?